# Registro duplicado no banco de dados

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Boa noite pessoal. Estou precisando de uma ajuda para remover alguns registros duplicados da tabela do meu banco de dados MySQL 5.7

Executando a seguinte query eu consigo identificar quais registros estão duplicados:

```
SELECT source_id, COUNT(*) TOTAL 
FROM news 
GROUP BY source_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer para deletar os registros duplicados e deixar apenas a original após o comando SELECT acima.

Comment: E como você identifica qual dos registros com source_id duplicado é o original? Se não é permitido duplicar não é melhor colocar este campo como chave primário ou como UNIQUE?

Comment: Use o `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: Se a tabela tiver um ID sequencial pode simplesmente fazer um join da tabela com ela mesma: `JOIN ON a.source_id = b.source_id AND id_sequencial != MIN( id_sequencial )` efetivamente filtrando as "originais" com id_unico menor. os id_unico retornados serão os que devem ser deletados (teste antes, claro). Se não tiver ID id_unico, grande chance de ter problemas mais sérios que a deleção. Dá pra fazer tudo em uma operação só, mas teste com um SELECT (subquery com join) antes de trocar por DELETE. Não esqueça do mais importante, que é arrumar a aplicação para que o problema sequer aconteça.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai precisar cumprir uma série de passos.

1. Crie uma tabela temporária chamada news_tmp
2. Faça um `SELECT DISTINCT` na tabela news para pegar somente um registro e ignorar duplicidades. No select, coloque as colunas, exceto a coluna de chave primária.
3. Depois rode um `INSERT INTO` assim:

   ```
   INSERT INTO news_temp (campoA, campoB)
     SELECT DISTINCT campoA, campoB
     FROM news;
   ```
4. `DROP TABLE news;`
5. `RENAME TABLE news_temp TO news;`

Infelizmente sua chave primária deve ser desprezada. Se precisar manter o valor da chave primária, precisará fazer um algorítimo com outra linguagem de programação.

Comment: É uma saída, ele pode inspecionar a news_temp para ver se deu tudo certo antes de fazer o drop, mas se ele tem chave primária pode simplesmente fazer um DELETE dos repetidos em uma operação SQL só, e ainda vai manter a chave primária. Vide meu comentário na pergunta.

Comment: Mandou bem @Bacco! Isso aí! +1 pela review!